# Can anyone identify this type of shutoff valve?

Tags: valve, shutoff

What type of shut off valve is this, and can I replace it with a quarter turn ball compression valve?
[image]

Comment: That looks like just a standard shut off valve. And, yes, you can replace with a 1/4 turn valve - one of my favorite things to do for the house supply and all toilets. (The similar valve in my house was tucked away in the back of a under-sink cabinet, making it all but impossible to get at, much less turn particularly after 40 years of rusting.)

Comment: @JonCuster  Type this up as an answer.

Comment: `ball` and `compression` are mutually exclusive valve types

Answer (score 1):

That is a standard sweated valve, if it is leaking they are easy to repair and much cheaper than a new valve. Most of the time a new seat (rubber seat that stops the water) and a new stem packing under the nut that holds the stem in place is all that is needed to fix a leaking valve , if it is leaking at the hose fitting that was probably over tightened , the plastic ones today break when over tightened those metal ones sometimes held but it looks like it is leaking. , replacing the valve with a 1/4 turn you will probably have to replace the hose also. I have a kit of faucet seats and valve packings / gortex rope that I got many years ago 10$ fixed probably 30 valves I still have the nice little metal box and buy rubber seats to refill you might consider a valve repair kit as looking at the age your home probably has 15+ total valves you could repair for the cost of 1 or possibly 2 new valves.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard sweat valve.  It would be easy to either cut or sweat it off.  An easy replacement would be a Sharkbite quarter-turn valve that matches your hose connection.